# Remove a word from a sentence (string)

Tags: c

I am in the stage of preparing myself for exams, and the thing that I m least proud of are my skills with strings. What I need to do is remove a word from a sentence, without using `<string.h>` library at all. 
This is what I've got so far. It keeps showing me that certain variables are not declared, such as start and end.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Side function to count the number of letters of the word we wish to remove */
int count(char *s) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (*s++) {
        counter++;
        s--;
    return counter;
}

/* Function to remove a word from a sentence */
char *remove_word(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    int counter2 = 0;
    /* We must remember where the string started */
    const char *toReturn = s1;
    /* Trigger for removing the word */
    int found = 1;
    /* First we need to find the word we wish to remove [Don't want to
      use string.h library for anything associated with the task */
    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        const char *p = s1;
        const char *q = s2;
        if (*p == *q) 
           const char *start = p;
        while (*p++ == *q++) {
            counter2++;
            if (*q != '\0' && counter2 < count(s2))
                found = 0;
            else {
                const char *end = q;
            }
        }
        /* Rewriting the end of a sentence to the beginning of the found word */
        if (found) {
            while (*start++ = *end++)
               ;
        }
        s1++;
    }
    return toReturn;
}

void insert(char niz[], int size) {
    char character = getchar();
    if (character == '\n')
        character = getchar();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size - 1 && character != '\n') {
        array[i] = character;
        i++;
        character = getchar();
    }
    array[i] = '\0';
}

int main() {
    char stringFirst[100];
    char stringSecond[20];

    printf("Type your text here: [NOT MORE THAN 100 CHARACTERS]\n");
    insert(stringFirst, 100);
    printf("\nInsert the word you wish to remove from your text.");
    insert(stringSecond, 20);
    printf("\nAfter removing the word, the text looks like this now: %s", stringFirst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `start` and `end` are defined _inside_ blocks and therefore are visible in that block only. If you wish to use it outside the block, define those variables outside

Comment: Managed to get `start` in the block, but can't figure out what to do with `end`. It needs to point to the end of the found sentece.

Comment: Removing a word from a string requires some proficiency in C. In my old library, I wrote four functions to achieve that.

Comment: @machine_1 Well, is my code far from being right? Pretty much the only problem I have is remembering the end of the found word, after that, overwriting over it is a piece of cake.

Comment: @Rose.: The easiest of this string finding - is brute force. O(N^2) but if you do finer then it will be KMP or so on...let's suppose you want Brute force,,and string replacemement? let's do that in 2 pass...can you do this?

Comment: @coderredoc Couldn't fully understand you as English isn't my native language. I'm not familiar with KMP, so brute force it is then, I guess. My logic is next: Find the word you want to replace (my code does that), declare a pointer to the beginning of that word, declare a pointer to the end of a sentence. Now just paste from the end, to the beginning. As you can see, I have issues declaring the `end`.

Comment: @Rose.: WHy do you need the end of the sentence? You find the word to remove and then simply the next letters from there which is not part of any of the target word will be placed. Simply put, whenever you find a word, replace them with some character that will not appear in the sentence... (like `=` etc...) and then you just remove those equal signs..isnt it easy for making the first try with these changes (I mean the `=` and so on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted you code for small indentation problems and indeed indentation problems indicate real issues:

- There is a missing `}` in `count`. It should read:

  ```
  /* Side function to count the number of letters of the word we wish to remove */
  int count(char *s) {
      int counter = 0;
      while (*s++) {
          counter++;
      }
      return counter;
  }
  ```

  or better:

  ```
  /* Side function to count the number of letters of the word we wish to remove */
  int count(const char *s) {
      const char *s0 = s;
      while (*s++) {
          continue;
      }
      return s - s0;
  }
  ```

  This function counts the number of bytes in the string, an almost exact clone of `strlen` except for the return type `int` instead of `size_t`. Note also that you do not actually use nor need this function.
- Your function `insert` does not handle `EOF` gracefully and refuses an empty line.  Why not read a line with `fgets()` and strip the newline manually:

  ```
  char *input(char buf[], size_t size) {
       size_t i;
       if (!fgets(buf, size, stdin))
           return NULL;
       for (i = 0; buf[i]; i++) {
           if (buf[i] == '\n') {
               buf[i] = '\0';
               break;
           }
      }
      return buf;
  }
  ```
- In function `remove_word`, you should define `start` and `end` with a larger scope, typically the outer `while` loop's body. Furthermore `s1` should have type `char *`, not `const char *`, as the phrase will be modified in place.
- You should only increment `p` and `q` if the test succeeds and you should check that `p` and `q` are not both at the end of their strings.
- last but not least: you do not call `remove_word` in the `main` function.

The complete code can be simplified into this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Function to remove a word from a sentence */
char *remove_word(char *s1, const char *s2) {
    if (*s2 != '\0') {
        char *dst, *src, *p;
        const char *q;
        dst = src = s1;
        while (*src != '\0') {
            for (p = src, q = s2; *q != '\0' && *p == *q; p++, q++)
                continue;
            if (*q == '\0') {
                src = p;   /* the word was found, skip it */
            } else {
                *dst++ = *src++;  /* otherwise, copy this character */
            }
        }
        *dst = '\0';  /* put the null terminator if the string was shortened */
    }
    return s1;
}

char *input(char buf[], size_t size) {
     size_t i;
     if (!fgets(buf, size, stdin))
         return NULL;
     for (i = 0; buf[i]; i++) {
         if (buf[i] == '\n') {
             buf[i] = '\0';
             break;
         }
    }
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char stringFirst[102];
    char stringSecond[22];

    printf("Type your text here, up to 100 characters:\n");
    if (!input(stringFirst, sizeof stringFirst))
        return 1;

    printf("\nInsert the word you wish to remove from your text: ");
    if (!input(stringSecond, sizeof stringSecond))
        return 1;

    printf("\nAfter removing the word, the text looks like this now: %s\n",
           remove_word(stringFirst, stringSecond));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So my logic wasn't that bad, just had a bit of a faulty implementation. I have two questions regarding your correction of my code: All those `for` loops I could have kept as `while` loops? And also, isn't the `count` function actually needed? The assignment says "Remove a word", word != string. The program fails to return correct result in next case scenario: I have a next sentence: The gardner's working around his house. I want to remove "garden". Garden isn't part of the sentence, but it will still remove "garden, and leave "er". That's why I needed `count` function.

Comment: Also, one more thing, what's the first `if` line in `remove_word` function for? Ensuring that the word we're looking for even exists or what?

Comment: @Rose: The first `if` tests if the word to remove has at least one character. The `while` loop would never terminate if `s2` points to an empty string.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank You.

Comment: I forgot about it, there you go. But I'm still lacking 3 points to upvote, nevermind. Again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

your code is badly formed, i strongly suggest compiling with:
gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -Werror -D_DEBUG -g (or similar)

- start with declaring your variables at the beginning of the function block, they are known only inside the block they are declared in.
- your count function is buggy, missing a closing '}'  (it doesn't compile)
  should be something like

  ```
  size_t Strlen(const char *s)
  {
      size_t size = 0;
      for (; *s != '\n'; ++s, ++size)
      {}
      return size;
  }
  ```
- implementing memmove is much more efficient then copy char by char

Comment: `memmove` is not needed if the string is tested and copied in one pass.

Comment: I know it won't compile, I've fixed it as soon as I've posted. As far as declaring variables, I have to declare them withing the `if` and `while` so I can remember where I was. Or is there another way?

Comment: @Rose: you should set their value where appropriate, but they should be declaring them in the `if` commanded statement is error prone and confusing. You should declare them before the `if` statement, preferably at the beginning of the `while` loop.

Comment: @chqrlie Oh I see, how couldn't I get that by myself is a mystery. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `start` and `end` pointers are defined within a block which makes their scope limited within that block. So, they are not visible to other parts of your code, and if you attempt to reference them outside their scope, the compiler will complain and throw an error. You should declare them at the beginning of the function block.

That said, consider the following approach to delete a word from a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int delete_word(char *buf,
    const char *word);


int main(void)
{
    const char word_to_delete[] = "boy";

    fputs("Enter string: ", stdout);

    char buf[256];
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

    if (delete_word(buf, word_to_delete)) 
    {
        printf("Word %s deleted from buf: ", word_to_delete);
        puts(buf);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Word %s not found in buf: ", word_to_delete);
        puts(buf);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


int chDelimit(int ch)
{
    return
        (ch == '\n' || ch == '\t') ||
        (ch >= ' ' && ch <= '/') ||
        (ch >= ':' && ch <= '@') ||
        (ch >= '[' && ch <= '`') ||
        (ch >= '{' && ch <= '~') ||
        (ch == '\0');
}

char *find_pattern(char *buf,
    const char *pattern)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while (*buf)
    {
        while (buf[n] && pattern[n])
        {
            if (buf[n] != pattern[n])
            {
                break;
            }
            n++;
        }
        if (!pattern[n])
        {
            return buf;
        }
        else if (!*buf)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        n = 0;
        buf++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *find_word(char *buf,
    const char *word)
{
    char *ptr;
    size_t wlen;

    wlen = strlen(word);
    ptr = find_pattern(buf, word);

    if (!ptr)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (ptr == buf)
    {
        if (chDelimit(buf[wlen]))
        {
            return ptr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (chDelimit(ptr[-1]) &&
            chDelimit(ptr[wlen]))
        {
            return ptr;
        }
    }

    ptr += wlen;
    ptr = find_pattern(ptr, word);
    while (ptr)
    {
        if (chDelimit(ptr[-1]) &&
            chDelimit(ptr[wlen]))
        {
            return ptr;
        }
        ptr += wlen;
        ptr = find_pattern(ptr, word);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int delete_word(char *buf,
    const char *word)
{
    size_t n;
    size_t wlen;

    char *tmp;
    char *ptr;

    wlen = strlen(word);
    ptr = find_word(buf, word);

    if (!ptr) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = ptr - buf;
        tmp = ptr + wlen;
    }

    ptr = find_word(tmp, word);
    while (ptr)
    {
        while (tmp < ptr)
        {
            buf[n++] = *tmp++;
        }
        tmp = ptr + wlen;
        ptr = find_word(tmp, word);
    }
    strcpy(buf + n, tmp);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You should not hard-code your character classes this way, better use the functions from `<ctype.h>`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to do it manually, just loop over the indicies of your string to find the first one that matches and than you’ll have a second loop that loops for all the others that matches and resets all and jumps to the next index of the first loop if not matched something in order to continue the searching. If I recall accuretaly, all strings in C are accesible just like arrays, you’ll have to figure it out how. Don’t afraid, those principles are easy! C is an easy langugae, thiught very long to write.

In order to remove: store the first part in an array, store the second part in an array, alloc a new space for both of them and concatinate them there.

Thanks, hit the upvote button. 
Vitali

EDIT: use \0 to terminate your newly created string.

Comment: As I said, I'm preparing for exam, rules are next: You have to use pointers and no side arrays allowed. And dynamic allocation is a bit too much for me.

Comment: well, you can always check out how strings are allocated and move one by one each characyer from the right to the left and append EOF string next to it :)